# Dokka failure: com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiClassImpl cannot be cast to com.intellij.psi.PsiJavaFile

Tags: android, gradle, aar, kotlin-dokka

I have a build that generates Android artefacts (mainly an `.aar`) and bundles in `dokka`-generated docs (codebase is Kotlin+Java).

With some recent changes `dokka` started failing with this cryptic error:

```
> Task :mylib:dokka FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mylib:dokka'.
> com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiClassImpl cannot be cast to com.intellij.psi.PsiJavaFile
```

Any help would be appreciated. I currently cannot seem to trace the source of this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't pin-point the root of the problem but I can say for sure that `Dokka` has some issues with [annotation classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html).

In my changes, I had initially introduced a new annotation class based on Android's [`@IntDef`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/IntDef) inside an abstract class (alongside associated helper methods), written in Java.

These 2 steps seemed to have helped:

1. Switching to Kotlin for the annotation class' implementation, then defining the annotation class at a **file's root scope** (rather than as an inner item of a class).
2. Suppressing the annotation's package in Dokka's config, i.e. -

```
dokka {
  ...

  packageOptions {
    prefix = "com.mylib.myannotation"
    suppress = true
  }
}
```

The end result is that the documentation cannot reference the annotated class (that's no surprise, as it was suppressed), but the javadoc generation fully succeeded.

Comment: In my case, I only had to take step #1 to resolve the ClassCastException. I did not have to suppress the new package where the annotation exists. In fact, in most cases all I did was move the annotation from an inner class to a top-level class in the same package, and it resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Interesting! I don't recall now what the error was before applying step #2, but if I recall correctly it failed to parse.